# How to make minimal but significant edits?

Tags: discussion, edits

Here an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8128312

This answer has an error, as mentioned in the comments there. (If you compare with strings one should use `==` and not `===`)

Now this is significant, because that little sign makes the code not working as it should. I can not edit it, because I would have to edit at least 7 chars, and the owner of the answer just does not do it.

So how to handle that?

**EDIT:** this was a bad example because it is not clearly a fault to use `===`. But my question is not answerd or uninteressting because of that. Better Example:

```
if ( a = 3) {
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about that edit? Paul Dixon's answer also uses a `===` to compare strings. I think you are misreading the comment.

Comment: To use `===` for string comparison is a bad habit, because you check if those strings are both the same Object. Strings with the same content do not necessairy have to be the same Object, so using `==` (compare content) wolud be better.

Comment: Well, that appears to be debatable. See the comments to Paul's answer again. There is significant disagreement among members of the Javascript community about whether using `==` or `===` is "best practice." You can do whatever you want in your own answers, of course, but this isn't a clear-cut case of a typo, so you shouldn't be editing your preferences into anyone else's answer.

Comment: @CodyGray May be a bad example, the experts are discussing  which to use..

Comment: I found this small and obscure project "jQuery" btw, maybe you've heard of it? It has a [style guide](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#equality) which says: *"Strict equality checks (===) must be used in favor of abstract equality checks (==). The only exception is when checking for undefined and null by way of null. The use of == null is also acceptable in cases where only one of null or undefined may be logically encountered, such as uninitialized variables."* No mention of `==` for strings. I believe the only problem is when using `new String()`. Don't do that and you're fine.

Comment: I bet you could fix that with some jQuery, @Carpetsmoker

Comment: 1) Primitive strings are not objects. 2) When you compare two primitive strings, both `==` and `===` check if they are exactly the same sequence of code units. 3) Not sure why you think `==` is better in this case. 4) IMO it's good the system didn't allow you to do this edit

Answer (score 1):

Don't make edits that change code, unless it's a *very* clear typo (e.g. Strinf instead of String).

If I were reviewing an edit that has code changes (even if the original code is buggy), I will reject it for the reason:

> **clearly conflicts with author's intent** 
>   
> This edit deviates from the
>   original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes
>   should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Instead, you should mention that in comments, and it's up to OP whether to accept it or not.

---

**After OP's Edit**

Again, your example is not good. Assignment inside a condition is a legal operation in most programming languages. In such cases I prefer to comment to OP and make him fix the typo, but in rare cases where I *know* the user and I'm sure that it should be `==`, I might correct <strike>and write a note for OP</strike> the code.

Comment: So if OP is no longer active, the comutity has to handle a bad/ **incorrect** answer? Clearly what SO needs... *sarcasm *

Comment: @inetphantom It's not "incorrect". It's your personal opinion that `===` is somehow always "wrong". Others disagree.

Comment: @inetphantom If the answer is **incorrect** then it should be downvoted, this way the community will know something is wrong with it.

Comment: *Obvious* (yet trivial) typos can be corrected by trusted users with full editing privileges, @inet, so we don't simply have to accept that an otherwise good answer will be plagued by a typo. As has been pointed out, that is not the case with your original example. And more broadly, as has been discussed countless times on Meta, users who have only privileges to *suggest* edits are prevented from making excessively trivial edits (defined as < 6 characters changed) because reviewing suggested edits requires the attention of 3 different reviewers who could be otherwise improving the site.

Comment: @inetphantom you could always add your own answer

Comment: Just FYI, @Maroun, you don't have to leave a comment when you edit someone's answer. They will already receive a notification in their inbox that their answer was edited. If your edit summary is descriptive (which it should be anyway), then they'll be able to figure out what you've done. That avoids cluttering up the comments and having to remember to go back later and delete them.

Comment: @CodyGray good point.

Answer (score 1):

If there is **really** an obvious **objective** error you can work around it by including a a comment at the bottom:

```
<!-- work around character limit -->
```

For an example see [this suggested edit of me](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/83315) at the Unix.SE site. This edit only changed whitespace, but this whitespace broke the code and was very obviously not what the author had intended (as it will error out).

What are **not** good reasons:

- "Fixing" the code to what you consider "good practice". Using `==` instead of `===` is not even universally accepted to be a "good practice" in JavaScript (and for good reason if you ask me). The same applies to using `==` (instead of `===`) for integer comparison, by the way.
- Edits that are *probably* unintended. Especially if the answer has been on the site for a while and has a few upvotes, it might just be that what you consider an "error" was actually intended. This is what might be the case in your `==` vs. `=` example. I don't think I've ever actually *seen* this error on Stack Overflow in an answer, by the way, not in an answer that was actually worth worrying about, anyway.
- More or less anything else that will not give an error or changes code in such a way that it actually *does something else*.